# How to encode a column containing (Let's say more than 200) categorical value in Machine Learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I want to encode a column (say Name - containing names of 1000 or more cars). I tried OneHotEncoding the column by using the code:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct= ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder',OneHotEncoder(),[0,1,4,5,6])],remainder='passthrough')
x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x))
```

When i ran this line of code it gave 2 errors- 1)  could not convert string to float:
2)  For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or convertible to a numeric.

Is there any ways to encode the column containing 1000 or more categorical value?

Comment: Try passing `x.astype('category')` to fit_transform

Comment: Or use `np.unique` to generate a numerical index